# How can I modify serial number on an off brand tablet?

Tags: rooting

I am trying to connect to a tablet with Android Studio.  The tablet is a Fusion5 Tablet F704B.  It's a low cost tablet with Oreo 8.1 OS.  I only have this tablet connected to my PC.   Android Studio does show 1 connected device, but it is labeled only as "Unknown"

[image]

When I hit the run app button in Android Studio, the gradle builds fine and then I see a "Error Installing APK"

[image]

I do more debug and run "adb devices" I see:

[image]

Note:  On the tablet, I do have developer mode enabled and have USB Debugging enabled.  I have tried USB Configuration to Charging, MTP, PTP, and USB Ethernet and nothing allowed allowed adb devices to see the tablet serial number.  I have also tried Multiple USB cables to connect the tablet, and that did allow the tablet serial number to be shown.  I have also connected other tablets I own, and they all show a serial number correctly.  I can run my app via android studio on 4 other tablets that I own.  Just not on this Fusion5 tablet.

I believe the lack of a serial number in this Fusion5 tablet is causing my issue with Android Studio.  After some research, I found that the serial number is contained in the tablet OS at /sys/class/android_usb/android0/iSerial.  This file needs root access to edit.  Using "adb shell", I can navigate to the directory, but can't view the file contents without root access.  I believe the file is has no content.  I believe this because the value iSerial shows as blank when I do a "lsusb -v" on my computer.

I have spent many hours researching how to give my tablet root access, but the first step involves loading the TWRP recovery image.  The twrp recovery images exist for many phones/tablets, but not for this odd offbrand cheap tablet.

I have also tried to bypass TWRP and perform an adp sideload , but fails with the default recovery routine that comes with my tablet.

Does anyone know of a way to edit the serial number field without root access?
Or is there some other clever way to get me root access I am missing?

Comment: Here is a way to change the Serial Number on an MTK device [Change Wifi , BT , IMEI , Serial Number of any mtk android phone](https://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/android-one-general/change-wifi-bt-imei-serial-mtk-android-t3058850). I haven't tried this yet. If you try it please let us know how it went.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209020/serial-number-got-changed-after-factory-reset